# How to pass generic class object as ref to another method?

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass the AVLTree object reference to another method.

Definition of AVLTree class => class AVLTree : IComparable> where T : IComparable

Code

```
 Addhere(ref AVLTree<T> currentNode); //Passing like this


 public void Addhere(ref AVLTree<T> currentNode) //Receiving like this
        {

        }
```

Error is =>  "using the generic type AVLTree(T) requires 1 argument"

Comment: Does [the example in the ref keyword documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#passing-an-argument-by-reference) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare it outside and pass

`AVLTree<T> currentnode = null;
Addhere(ref currentnode);`